# Binding a variable though ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Given the following controller code

```
var NamesCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['Bamse', 'Skalman'];
  $scope.kill = function(name) {
    $scope.names.splice(indexOf(name), 1);
  }
};
```

Can I call the the kill function with the current name as parameter (I.e something like this)?

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
  {{name}} 
  <input type="Button" ng-click="kill(name)" value="Kill"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes and this line should be `$scope.names.splice($scope.names.indexOf(name), 1);`

Comment: Hehe thank you, seems it was just problems not related to angular in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the name to a function in your controller, but there is an easier and more "Angular" way. You can use a built in Angular variable for `ngRepeat` called `$index`. You can use this as the index of the array element.

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
  {{name}} 
  <input type="Button" ng-click="kill($index)" value="Kill"/>
</div>
```

Now in your controller your kill function can be:

```
$scope.kill = function(index) {
    $scope.names.splice(index, 1);
}
```